# pivot table sum in R and stacked bar chart

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called graphexpDS which has 100's transactions, snippet of data below;

```
sub_category     category           exp_pw
Fruit & veg      Food               21.1
Meat             Food               25.2
Rent             Housing            787.45
Grocery food     Food               60.2
Soft drinks      Food               13.8
Meat             Food               88.5
Medical          Health             77.4
```

I want to sum the 'exp_pw' column for each unique value in 'sub_category', like a pivot table in excel. I've tried this code, but its returning an error, it also doesnt account for the category column which needs to remain for the graph i plan to create after

```
graphexpDS <- graphexpDS %>%
aggregate(x= graphexpDS$exp_pw, by = list(graphexpDS$sub_category), FUN = sum)
```

error from sum code:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): invalid 'type' (list) of argument
Traceback:

1. graphexpDS %>% aggregate(x = graphexpDS$exp_pw, by = list(graphexpDS$nzhec_short), 
 .     FUN = sum)
2. aggregate(., x = graphexpDS$exp_pw, by = list(graphexpDS$nzhec_short), 
 .     FUN = sum)
3. aggregate.default(., x = graphexpDS$exp_pw, by = list(graphexpDS$nzhec_short), 
 .     FUN = sum)
4. aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...)
5. lapply(x, function(e) {
 .     ans <- lapply(X = unname(split(e, grp)), FUN = FUN, ...)
 .     if (simplify && length(len <- unique(lengths(ans))) == 1L) {
 .         if (len == 1L) {
 .             cl <- lapply(ans, oldClass)
 .             cl1 <- cl[[1L]]
 .             ans <- unlist(ans, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
 .             if (!is.null(cl1) && all(vapply(cl, identical, NA, 
 .                 y = cl1))) 
 .                 class(ans) <- cl1
 .         }
 .         else if (len > 1L) 
 .             ans <- matrix(unlist(ans, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), 
 .                 ncol = len, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = if (!is.null(nms <- names(ans[[1L]]))) 
 .                   list(NULL, nms))
 .     }
 .     ans
 . })
6. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
7. lapply(X = unname(split(e, grp)), FUN = FUN, ...)
```

I then plan on creating a stacked bar chart where each 'category' is a bar and each 'sub_category' within the categories is a stack.

my code for this so far is:

```
##stacked bar chart for expenditure breakdowns
ggplot(graphexpDS, aes(fill=sub_category, y=exp_pw, x=category)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",
             width = 0.6,
             color = "black",
             size = 0.5,
             alpha = 0.7)
```

but I've been unable to test it due to the first error, but if you could spot any issues with it I would appreciate that also :)

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need pipe here. Try `aggregate(x= graphexpDS$exp_pw, by = list(graphexpDS$sub_category), FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with using a library:

```
library(tidyverse)
graphexpDS %>% group_by(sub_category, category) %>% summarize(total = sum(exp_pw))
```

Because category is included in the group_by() call, it should stick around in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(graphexpDS)[, .(total = sum(exp_pw)), .(sub_category, category)]
```